# Mouse events start being ignored after some time under some conditions

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I developed a jQuery plugin which has a 'reset' function which basically removes certain DOM elements, apply some CSS and restore the original DOM element (the one to which I apply the plugin) state.

Specifically, the reset (which I believe to be the source of the issue) does:

- remove DOM elements by...

  ```
  $(selector).remove();
  ```
- replace element's classes (but I use the element's ID to re-init the element which works with no issues in fact) by

  ```
  $(selector).className = existingClasses; # existing classes is set on first plugin init()
  ```
- unbind mouse events (**namespace**-defined) by

  ```
  $('body').off('.rbMouseEventHandler')
  $('#otherElement').off('.rbMouseEventHandler')
  ```
- replace original DOM element by

  ```
  var object = $(initialState.selector)
  object.html(initialState);
  ```
- restore element's original style (assuming no inline style was defined for it)

  ```
  object.attr('style', '');
  ```

However this leads to issues with events, especially with `mousemove` (both on desktop-Chrome and mobile-Android).
I noticed this happens only after reset.

Particularly it happens with:

```
    $('body').on('mousemove mouseup mousedown', function(evt){
        console.log(evt.type);
    }
```

Mousemove stops being triggered after some time while with other mouse events (e.g. `mouseup`, `mousedown`) it seems working normally.

I checked events binding in Chrome's DevTools and they seem to be there. Unfortunately I have no way to reproduce it as it happens randomly.

Comment: using `$('body').off('.rbMouseEventHandler')` you aren't removing these events bound using: `$('body').on('mousemove mouseup mousedown', handler);`. `mousemove` can be called hundred times, if not more. If you are rebinding it many times, you could break in some way the console, no more able to handle so many logs. Could it be your issue?

Comment: `$(selector).className` doesn't do anything. `className` is a DOM element property, not a jQuery property.

Comment: Use `$(selector).addClass(existingClasses)`

Comment: A.Wolff the last piece of code was just an example. However I refactored the code and handled the cases when the event would not be fired (the reason why it's not yet clear)
@Barmar what's wrong with using className instead of addClass? I just directly set the property instead of using addClass (which is anyhow a viable solution)

Comment: @dragonmnl You have to set the property on the DOM element(s), not the jQuery object. E.g. `$(selector).get(0).className = ...`

Comment: @Barmar thank you. I think I did it. Since  I made several changes to the code since my answer I probably did that as well. In fact each time the new className is output when I request it